# position:fixed ios 6.1 not working when viewport meta tag is defined

Tags: iphone, html, css, ios6

I am building a responsive site that uses fixed position elements. I have noticed a strange bug in iOS 6.1 where if I have defined any values for the meta viewport tag, for example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Then my fixed position elements do the classic, move-and-jump-back. If I remove the meta tag, the site layout is obviously wrong, but fixed positioning works great.

Basic HTML/CSS:

```
<h1><span>My Title</span></h1>

h1{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin:0 !important;
    background: url(logo_mobile.png) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
    cursor: pointer;
    span{ display:none; }
}
```

Is this behaviour expected? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Are you using any CSS transforms only when the viewport is below the 960px?

Comment: Yes, I'm transforming a completely different element - scaling and translating

Comment: I've run into issues with transforms on parent elements screwing with position fixed children. Could that be happening here?

Comment: No I don't think so - the element I'm scaling is completely separate to the element where position fixed is applied...

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is with the "width=device-width," tag.  That tag can cause issues.  Try implementing your own detection system or using an out of the box one because to rely on what the viewport determines your height/width to be can prove tricky in the future.  A concept I am playing around with is using javascript to rewrite the tag and to be able to pass a better calculated value than relying on device-width:

```
      for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) {
        if (metas[i].name == "viewport") {
          metas[i].content = "initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1";
        }
      }
```

So far I have had good results.  Hope it helps.